# Script for secure cPanel login with PHP

Tags: php, curl, cpanel

Since recently, cPanel has changed the way that it logs in.

Before login, the url is : **https://accessurl:2083/**

After login : **https://accessurl:2083/cpsessXXXX/frontend/x3/index.html?post_login=89711792346495**

You will note the **cpsessXXXX** embedded in the url.

And the page to access AWSTATS is :**https://accessurl:2083/cpsessXXXX/awstats.pl?config=domain_name&ssl=&lang=en**

I have tried the following PHP code

```
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$loginUrl = 'https://<accessurl>';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT,2083);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I step through the code, the value of **$store** is FALSE, meaning that the login process failed.

The only reference that I found on the web to a similar problem is
at http://blog.mcfang.com/ in the March 28 entry.

I was hoping that cookies.txt would have the cpsessXXXX info, but no file is created.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference the security token back to cPanel in order for your script to be accepted. As per the documentation over at [cPanel documentation for Security tokens](http://blog.cpanel.net/making-your-script-work-with-security-tokens-in-cpanel-whm/)

Take the following example:

```
function createSession() { // Example details
$ip = "127.0.0.1";
$cp_user = "username";
$cp_pwd = "password";
$url = "http://$ip:2082/login";
$cookies = "/path/to/storage/for/cookies.txt";

// Create new curl handle
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies); // Save cookies to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$cp_user&pass=$cp_pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100020);

// Execute the curl handle and fetch info then close streams.
$f = curl_exec($ch);
$h = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// If we had no issues then try to fetch the cpsess
if ($f == true and strpos($h['url'],"cpsess"))
{
    // Get the cpsess part of the url
    $pattern="/.*?(\/cpsess.*?)\/.*?/is";
    $preg_res=preg_match($pattern,$h['url'],$cpsess);
}

// If we have a session then return it otherwise return empty string
return (isset($cpsess[1])) ? $cpsess[1] : "";
}
```

cpsess is used to append the URLs the correct token that cPanel expects back.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks. I altered the port to 2083, changed the login details and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The whole purpose of this is to automate the retrieval of AWSTATS. Everything works fine, except the returned HTML basically says "You must set AWStats UseFramesWhenCGI parameter to 0
to see your reports."
As this is a shared server, I cannot change the AWSTATS conf file for UseFramesWhenCGI = 0.
Is there a way to set this thru PHP curl? Or, how can I use curl to still receive a frameset page?

Comment: The answer is (for me :-)) to just look at the relevant frame which is **awstats.pl?month=11&year=2012&config=$domain&lang=en&&update=1&framename=mainright**

Answer (score 2):

You can send the "Authorization" row by Headers adding this simple row:

```
$header[0] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($cp_user.":".$cp_pwd) . "\n\r";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

So you can send a request directly to the resource $myResource, without cookies and anything else.
Simply:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myResource);
$header[0] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($cp_user.":".$cp_pwd) . "\n\r";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT,2083);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You should consider to use the [XML API of CPanel](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/CallingAPIFunctions). On Github you can find the [xmlapi-php class](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php), it works great and help me to keep the code simple and easy to update!