# Disabling Ajax/http success message?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

[Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/TruyqjsE)

Once this code has been successfully executed,

```
 $homepage = @file_get_contents("http://$cpuser:$cppass@$cpdomain:2082/frontend/$cpskin/mail/doaddpop.html?email=$emailname&domain=$emaildomain&password=$emailpass&quota=$quota");
echo $homepage;
```

This will show up on the screen and stops the page from running any other code.

[image]

If I take out the **echo $homepage**, the **$homepage**  doesn't get executed and it doesn't work.

How can I suppress that message from showing up ? I just want it to do it's job without telling me it finished. Is there some kind of **error_reporting(0);** like in PHP that I could use? although that's not exactly an error though.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!
Sorry for my last post, I should have included more information if I needed help. I read the help section so hopefully this is enough information for me to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: what does the file_get_contents() part of this achieve?

Comment: well that part logs me into cpanel and execute the add webmail command. For some reason, if I don't use that, it doesn't work o.o

Comment: what is the value of $homepage after calling it, is it the error message you link to in your question?

Comment: I tried using fopen() and fclose() but it just doesn't like me :|
when I switched to file_get_content it worked

Comment: cURL doesn't work because cPanel has a security token or session ID.

Comment: use cURL, the answer to the reason it's not working (with cURL) is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13692440/1352271

Comment: Thank you for showing me that!
how do I mark this as answered? Or what do I need to do now that my question have been answered?
I don't want to just delete it because someone else might have the same problem as me.

Comment: U can't mark comments as answers :P

Answer (score 0):

use cURL, the answer to the reason it's not working (with cURL) is in this question: stackoverflow.com/a/13692440/1352271